# AngularJS: Differential REST update to avoid flashing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have an array of `Device` objects which is fetched regularly from a REST server using `$resource`. Whenever this happens, the UI gets "reloaded", meaning the `ng-repeat` for this device array is executed again. The DOM update is annoying, because it screws up the current user interaction with devices. Instead I want the newly fetched `Device` array to update the existing one only WHERE stuff has changed. So if I get a fresh `Device` array, and there was only a name change in one of the 10 devices, then only that single data binding for that name of this one device shall incur a DOM update.

I couldn't find a method of doing this. Since it seems a common problem to me, I wanted to ask before writing my own "`mergeUpdate`" method which basically just does a deep-compare-replace operation and only write the things into the existing binding that actually have changed on the server-side.

Note that each device is uniquely identified by an `id`, thus this algorithm is possible at all. Without this `id` field it would not work (probably the reason why there is no generic method supplied with AngularJS).

Actually, `angular.equals` is a partial solution. Now I want something that can at least transfer modified properties too, without invalidating the whole array.

Thanks!

Comment: What if the latest reload of data gets a new set of devices in addition to the changes in existing devices? The mergeUpdate would not help then - right? The best way to handle this is for the user interaction with a device to be handle separately (ie, frozen) from the refresh. But this introduces a concurrency problem, ie, what if two or more users are interacting with a device. That could be resolved by "locking" the device.

Comment: Yes it would. it can just add the devices to the end of the array and delete removed ones as well. Although I am not sure if this will cause all the items to be reevaluated by angularJS. Still, new devices happen rarely and this should not have a notable UI impact. In the worst case, new/deleted devices could be offered via explicit "refresh", like in Google Mail. Locking is a very bad idea :D. I think in most cases Angular should be able to handle this scenario. It's just too common. The use-case is: Absolutely nothing has changed.

Comment: ok - in that case, one could make the ng-repeat conditional using a flag. And the moment the user starts working on a device, it would set the flag to false, thus preventing the ng-repeat from executing (but the underlying data will get refreshed). When the user is done with the device, flag=true and ng-repeat will execute with the next data refresh.

Comment: That's not really practical in my case. I was just looking for an "incremental" update, because it solves my problem the way I want. If that doesn't exist, then I will just write it myself ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is "track by" for ngrepeat.  In your case,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"></div>
```

With this, ngrepeat will keep track of existing items and not rerender them.  The merge logic is internal to ngrepeat.

Comment: Yep exactly what I wanted... You are my hero ;). I was expecting for it to be something that simple, since it must be so common.